# New NextCloud installation requires change but I'm not sure where to run this line of code

Tags: 16.04, command-line, mysql, nextcloud

I just installed NextCloud 15 on a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

The welcome page shows this:

> Some columns in the database are missing a conversion to big int. Due
>   to the fact that changing column types on big tables could take some
>   time they were not changed automatically. By running 'occ
>   db:convert-filecache-bigint' those pending changes could be applied
>   manually. This operation needs to be made while the instance is
>   offline. For further details read the documentation page about this.
>   filecache.mtime filecache.storage_mtime

Where do I run this command at and how:

```
occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

I tried running it on the command line and also the mysql command line. The command line said occ not found and mysql said it was bad syntax.

Where do I execute this line at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`occ` is a console script in the Nextcloud html directory, which should be per default located at `/var/www/html/nextcloud` or maybe `/var/www/nextcloud/`.

You can `cd` into that directory and run `./occ` from there:

```
cd /var/www/html/nextcloud
./occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

or run it from anywhere with full path provided:

```
/var/www/html/nextcloud/occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

---

> Note that the official documentation states that you must run `occ` as your HTTP user (which defaults to `www-data` in Debian/Ubuntu) to ensure that the correct permissions are maintained on your Nextcloud files and directories:
>   `sudo -u www-data php occ`
>   or `sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/nextcloud/occ`

See: [> Using the occ command](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html)

---

If you have installed [Nextcloud as a snap package](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap), you can run `occ` as `nextcloud.occ`.

```
nextcloud.occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

```
    sudo -u www-data php occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

Sorry to add - I had also ran sudo -i
otherwise the command would not run for me.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [an existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1101062/250300).

Answer (score -1):

This one working with me:

```
cd /var/www/html/nextcloud
sudo -u www-data ./occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```